# Eclipse ide always opens the first project in my project list

Tags: eclipse

Since Simrel 2023-09, I noticed that when I start the Eclipse IDE (PDT), it always automatically opens the first project on my project explorer. I am on 2023-12 and the behaviour persists.

The "first" project might be a misnomer. However, I have tried the following

- Closing the project and restarting. The first project is open
- Closing only the first project and restarting. The first project and other open projects are opened
- Closing all projects and restarting. The first project is open
- ... and other combinations

There are no errors, but it just gets in my way of having a cleaner workspace.

Please make recommendations of how to fix this.

Comment: Can this be reproduced with a fresh installation and a fresh workspace? If yes, can it also be reproduced with the latest developer build of the Eclipse SDK? It is highly recommended to make sure such things has been reported, best with a pull request that fixes the issue. Please use Stack Overflow only for real question.

Comment: I can not reproduce this in the _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_ 2023-12 on Windows 11. Might be related to [this](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/commit/35a5e7bfdc632a8ec9e752c8e068a010c2c346dc) and how you start Eclipse (a feature that you use inadvertently).

Comment: @howlger This is something in Eclipse itself, not the project settings. The projects in the project explorer as listed alphabetically. Deleting the topmost project results in the new topmost project being automatically opened.

Comment: @howlger I will try a fresh install and new workspace. I will have to  do some backups and exporting/importing before I start that. I will update in a week.